# Add an Event listener to the AxWindowsMediaPlayer.Ctlcontrols.currentPosition property c#

Tags: c#, events, listener, axwindowsmediaplayer

I am using the WindowsMediaPlayer element in a windows form and I would like to have an event listener that monitors the change of the Position property (double).

The built in Position changed event does not seems to be it.

How can I add an event without modifiying the orginal class or extending it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What you ask for is entirely not possible by any normal means. First, you can't "add an event" to a control without modifying its source (which obviously you don't have). Second, the WMP control **does not** notify about position-change in any way. That event you found is risen whenever the `currentPosition` changes due to things **other than playback**. So, if you set the position manually, the event will be risen. When you "play" the video - not. The `currentPosition` is meant for polling. The only way to "watch" the position changing due to playback is what **ChaseRocker** answered.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I went with ChaseRocker 's answer after all.It's not efficient but it does the job. I wanted to create a script where the video would pause when it reaches a specified time.

Answer (score 2):

Use a timer control or separate process to monitor the **Ctlcontrols.currentPosition** of the axwindowsmediaplayer and update your display.